# SQL Query Between Dates in Visual Studio Table

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio, date, between

I have a table within Visual Studio and I am wanting to create an input field in for a StartDate and another input field for an EndDate where a user selects a date for both and it will return all records that have a date that falls between the Start and End dates that the user chooses. I would also like the user to have the option to only search for the StartDate and leave the EndDate null so essentially only having 2 input fields for the table (or 1 if End Date is null).

I have this right now which returns the date the user selects but only on that date:

```
(Date = @Date) AND (@Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
```

@StartDate is a date that comes before any date in the DB. @EndDate is the current day. This is just in case a user types in a date that is not within the date range of the database and it will return an error.

I have tried making the parameter @StartDate equal to @Date so when the user selects a date, it will make that the starting date. I also have the input field for the user to select an EndDate which seems to work. I just can't get the start date parameter to work like I want.

These are the queries I have tried:

1.

```
(Date = @Date) AND (@StartDate = @Date) AND (@Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
```

2.

```
(Date = @Date) AND (@Date BETWEEN @Date AND @EndDate)
```

How do I modify this query/parameters to get the user to select a start date and an end date in input fields and for the table to return all the records that are between those dates?

Comment: Try to change first `AND` keywords of all of the three lines to `OR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `(Date = @Date) AND ...`

This will always require `Date` to equal `@Date` to be true, regardless of the rest unless some `OR ...` comes along.

Assuming the two fields fill `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` (to me it isn't clear, why there is a third variable, `@Date`) you're probably searching for something like:

```
@EndDate IS NULL
AND Date = @StartDate
 OR Date BETWEEN @StartDate
                 AND @EndDate
```

If `@EndDate IS NULL` (the user hasn't put anything in the respective field) `Date = @StartDate` has to be true. Otherwise `Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate` (which won't ever be true if `@EndDate IS NULL` just in case you wonder).

Comment: This is now returning all records in the DB. Even if I have the End date earlier than the start date.

Comment: @derekg8881: Please show the whole query, the table (as `CREATE` statement), sample data (as `INSERT` statement) and the values in the variables. Please do so by editing your question. Don't use comments or an answer.

Comment: Your original answer actually worked. I had to delete the parameter Date. Date was for the original query to just search for a single date. Deleting that and making the StartDate visible in order for the user to select a start date or a single date if end date is null solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Another quick question...since your original answer works, I have another input box for server name. How do I query a server name that is between the dates of the start and end date? This is the where clause and the last OR statement is my attempt at what I'm trying to accomplish: `(@EndDate IS NULL AND Date = @StartDate OR Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) 
OR (ServerName = @ServerName) 
OR  (Date = @StartDate AND Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND ServerName = @ServerName)`